# You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"propTypes":{}}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I updated Expo and I'm getting the following message for my Connection Screen where it's supposed to change the Screen title depending on if user is connected or not.

The bug comes from this line:

```
headerTitle: connect((state) => ({ children: this.getTitle(state) }))(Text)
```

And the error:

```
You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"propTypes":{}}
```

It worked fine before so I don't know what is going on.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import Form from '../components/Form';
import Wallpaper from '../components/Wallpaper';
import ButtonSubmit from '../components/ButtonSubmit';
import SignupSection from '../components/SignupSection';
import { Router, Scene, Actions, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import ErrorMessage from '../components/ErrorMessage';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {ifIphoneX} from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper'

import logoImg from '@assets/images/logo.png';

class ConnexionScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        getTitle=(state)=>{{
            if(state.login.status){
                return 'MON COMPTE'
            }
            return 'CONNEXION'         
        }
      }
}
    handleSubmit() {
        console.log(this.loginform);
      }
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: connect((state) => ({ children: this.getTitle(state) }))(Text),
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        ...ifIphoneX({marginTop:-55}),
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
  };
  render() {
      const { navigation, login } = this.props;
      const { status, email} = login;

    return (
        status === 0 ? (
        <Wallpaper>   
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="position" enabled>
                    <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:"row",alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center"}}>
                        <Image source={logoImg} style={styles.image} />
                    </View>
                    <ErrorMessage />
                    <Form />
                    <ButtonSubmit />
                    <View style={styles.OrContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.Ortext}>ou</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("VIP")}>
                            DEVENIR VIP
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{height:50}}></View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </Wallpaper>) :
            (
               <Wallpaper>  
                   <View style={{ flex: 1,flexDirection: "column",justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center"}}>
                <View style={{height:200}}> 
                    <Logo />
                </View>
                 <View>
                    <Text style={{ color: "rgba(255,204,51, 1)",fontSize: 18,fontFamily: "oswald-demi-bold"}}> {`Email : ${email}`}</Text>
                    <Text style={{color:'#fff',fontSize: 18,color: "rgba(255,255,255, 1)", textAlign:"center"}} onPress={() => this.props.logout()}> {`Logout`}</Text>
                </View>
                </View>
                </Wallpaper>
            )

    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({login}) => ({login});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    const loginAction = require('@redux/LoginRedux').default
    return {
        logout: () => dispatch(loginAction.logout()),
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnexionScreen)
```

The error I'm getting...Any help would be much appreciated!

```
You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"propTypes":{}}

wrapWithConnect
    connectAdvanced.js:101:29
<unknown>
    ConnexionScreen.js:32:74
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:292:12
<unknown>
    MainTabNavigator.js:17
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:292:12
<unknown>
    RootNavigation.js:6
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:292:12
<unknown>
    App.js:5
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:292:12
<unknown>
    AppEntry.js:2
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:292:12
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:179:45
global code
    <unknown file>:0
```

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = this.state.login.status;`

Comment: Could you change this?

Comment: The problem comes from this line: headerTitle: connect((state) => ({ children: this.getTitle(state) }))(Text),

Comment: in static element you can't call "this" from this.getTitle(state). "this" not understand here.

Comment: @HuyNguyen It was working well before Expo update...

Comment: @ÉmilieRobert you can try with any string value instead of using this.getTitle(...), you will see if work or not